# Is there an algorithm for finding a minimal subgraph that connects certain nodes?

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

This problem comes up in the context of game skilltrees, [for example in Path of Exile](https://www.pathofexile.com/fullscreen-atlas-skill-tree/AAAABgAAgAHAAxQFEwjkCfgLcQ7TEOEU2hWxGYIddB5bH8QkyyTvJlgm5yjQKOkqhCtBK2gr1zA1MIw0iDpGO9w-X0FfQYxDqUcNR89P2FNhU9tYRVibWKlafVqbXbdgIWBNY7VlfWWXZrVmxmfpadVsSXBAcQtxK3Lcc4t1E30-gHiDlIPdh_uIGYijiUKKyYrRixiNKY5qkX2RxJLXo26jiaSspm2m2qwfruevwbH7tu23gblpvte_FsHHw03GM8bQxtnHs8e0y8vNqM56z8nRTdL00zjUh9dW2J7ZhduH3yPfXuGL4qfjcOWP5k_nKOja6o3q0-rV7RPvrvHe9Xf6MP3J_t4AAA==). In this case, one wants to have a subgraph of the entire graph that connects all desired nodes to the origin, but contains as few nodes as possible. Is there an efficient algorithm for this, or a good heuristic? Or is it, as I suspect, NP-hard?

Simply using Dijkstra to determine the distances and then Kruskal to find a minimum spanning tree does not work. This is because the cost of connecting a subsequent node can depend on what nodes are already connected (and by which paths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem).  The decision problem is as follows:

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and a set of *terminal* vertices $T \subseteq V$ and a integer $k$, does there exist a set of at most $k$ edges $F \subseteq E$ such that $G' = (T, F)$ is connected.

The problem is indeed NP-complete, but on the positive side, it is solvable in *fixed parameter tractable* time $O(3^k (n+m))$.

There is an approximation algorithm too.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, that is the (NP-hard) Steiner tree problem in graphs. If you just care about the number of included vertices, you can simply set all edge weights to 1.
Please note that NP-hard does not mean at all that it is not efficiently solvable in practice.
Under "External links" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem
you find some efficient exact solvers for this problem, which provide optimal solutions to Steiner tree problems with tens of thousands of edges within seconds.